# Use certificate for HTTPS request in Java

Tags: java, ssl, https, pkcs#12

I want to call some web services through an HTTPS connection in Java. The certificate authority gave me a PKCS12 file but I get a

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

due to

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
```

Here is the code I am executing :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path/toto2.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pwd");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/toto2.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pwd");
System.setProperty("proxySet","true") ;
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "XXX") ;
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "XXX") ;
```

I first tried to give the PKCS12 file, then the JKS but I had the same error.

I tried another solution, with curl. So I extracted certificates from the PKCS12 and the requests successed.

Here are the commands that I used to extract the different files from the P12 :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out clientcert.key
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out clientcert.cer
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -chain -out cacerts.cer
```

Am I wrong with the way I use those files in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

PKCS12 normally contains a privatekey and cert (chain) combination, and is used to authenticate *your system* i.e. the client, which is done with the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` properties. You should specify type PKCS12, although some Java8 versions (only!) can read PKCS12 when you specify JKS.

It typically does NOT authenticate the server(s), which is what `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` is for, so don't use it there. Depending on the server(s?), you may or may not need a custom truststore different from the P12 and also different from Java's default. 
Look at the cert chain used by the server with a browser or other tool like `curl` or `keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port]`
and determine whether it uses a public root CA like Verisign-now-Symantec-now-Digicert or GoDaddy, which will already be in Java's default truststore, or a 'private' CA or even a self-signed cert, in which case you should either add that cert to the default truststore or if you can't or don't want to modify your JVM put that cert in a keystore file you use as the truststore.

PS: the `ValidatorException` *causes* the `SSLHandshakeException` not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I fixed the truststore issue by putting the CA into Java's default truststore. However, when I print the ssl debug, I still get the same exception. The subject of the certificate Java uses (from the keystore) is not the same as the one in the truststore. The p12 file (keystore) contains multiple certificates, how can I extract the one with the same subject as the truststore ?

Comment: I fixed the errors and the request works well now. I just had to five all CA's to the cacerts, one was missing so I downloaded it from the website.